# Spring, iText - Create PDF from many entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pdf, itext

I have 9 different entities with different count of fields
I'm trying to create PDF file from all of them. I've found this sollution for PDF creations:

```
public class PDFGenerator {

  private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PDFGenerator.class);

  public static ByteArrayInputStream customerPDFReport(List<Customer> customers) {
    Document document = new Document();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {

          PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);
            document.open();

            // Add Text to PDF file ->
          Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, 14, BaseColor.BLACK);
          Paragraph para = new Paragraph( "Customer Table", font);
          para.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
          document.add(para);
          document.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);

          PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
          // Add PDF Table Header ->
            Stream.of("ID", "First Name", "Last Name")
              .forEach(headerTitle -> {
                  PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell();
                  Font headFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD);
                  header.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);
                  header.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                  header.setBorderWidth(2);
                  header.setPhrase(new Phrase(headerTitle, headFont));
                  table.addCell(header);
              });

            for (Customer customer : customers) {
              PdfPCell idCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(customer.getId().toString()));
              idCell.setPaddingLeft(4);
              idCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
              idCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                table.addCell(idCell);

                PdfPCell firstNameCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(customer.getFirstName()));
                firstNameCell.setPaddingLeft(4);
                firstNameCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                firstNameCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                table.addCell(firstNameCell);

                PdfPCell lastNameCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(String.valueOf(customer.getLastName())));
                lastNameCell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
                lastNameCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
                lastNameCell.setPaddingRight(4);
                table.addCell(lastNameCell);
            }
            document.add(table);

            document.close();
        }catch(DocumentException e) {
          logger.error(e.toString());
        }

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
  }
}
```

This solution use `Stream.of("ID", "First Name", "Last Name")` and `customer.getId().toString()` but I don't know for which entity user want to create PDF, so I can't use get methods.

I need something like AbstractPDFGenerator which will create PDF for any count of entity fields and fill them without getters.

What's the best way to generate PDF for multiple entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this.... the # of columns is dependent on how many strings you have in your list. The input is a list made up of a many lists of strings. The outer list contains each row, the inner list contains each value in the row

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
    List<List<String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    List<String> headerRow = Arrays.asList( "ID", "First Name", "Last Name" );
    List<String> firstRow = Arrays.asList( "1", "Jon", "Snow" );
    List<String> secondRow = Arrays.asList( "2", "Mr", "Person" );

    rows.add( headerRow );
    rows.add( firstRow );
    rows.add( secondRow );

    File file = new File( "pathhhh" );
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();

    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream( customerPDFReport( rows ) );
    StreamUtils.copy( bais, new FileOutputStream( file ) );
}

public static byte[] customerPDFReport( List<List<String>> rows ) {
    Document document = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {

        PdfWriter.getInstance( document, out );
        document.open();

        // Add Text to PDF file ->
        Font font = FontFactory.getFont( FontFactory.COURIER, 14, BaseColor.BLACK );
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph( "Customer Table", font );
        para.setAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER );
        document.add( para );
        document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable( rows.get( 0 ).size() );
        List<String> headerRow = rows.remove( 0 ); // remove header

        for ( String value : headerRow ) {

            PdfPCell header = new PdfPCell();
            Font headFont = FontFactory.getFont( FontFactory.HELVETICA_BOLD );
            header.setBackgroundColor( BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY );
            header.setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER );
            header.setBorderWidth( 2 );
            header.setPhrase( new Phrase( value, headFont ) );
            table.addCell( header );

        }

        for ( List<String> wholeRow : rows ) {
            for ( String value : wholeRow ) {
                PdfPCell idCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase( value ) );
                idCell.setPaddingLeft( 4 );
                idCell.setVerticalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE );
                idCell.setHorizontalAlignment( Element.ALIGN_CENTER );
                table.addCell( idCell );
            }
        }

        document.add( table );

        document.close();
    } catch ( DocumentException e ) {

    }

    return out.toByteArray();
}
```